# Our form is giving the XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: httprequest, form, cors

I have researched and researched and tried everything out there on this SalesForce error we are getting. We were given an html form from Salesforce and it worked until we added our own conditional logic to a few of the questions. Now we keep getting this error and we would like to keep our conditional logic:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8&method=csrfToken. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://cms-test.alaska.edu' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know it has something to do with CORS but just not sure how to fix it.

Our form is located at: [https://cms-test-alaska.edu/admissions/info/](https://cms-test.alaska.edu/admissions/info/) which is outside of our Salesforce sandbox but it sends the information into our Salesforce sandbox area. But because of the type of the form and the way Salesforce works the Salesforce team said this form must live outside the Salesforce sandbox.

I am unsure where to go from here. Please help I am desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Add https://cms-test-alaska.edu/admissions/info/ to your remote site settings.